# Can I use property syntax for a Java setter without a corresponding getter?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop, kotlin1.4

I have a Java class with a setter, but no getter for a property.

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

I'd like to use `.name=` to assign to it from Kotlin

```
fun example() {
  val p = Person()
  p.name = "example"
}
```

I get an error `unresolved reference: name` trying to compile the Kotlin. The error goes away if I add a getter, but can I use the setter as a property without defining a getter in Java? I know I can still call `p.setName("example")` from kotlin.

The above is the MCVE. The *real world* code is a Java builder with setters but not getters which I'd like to use from Kotlin, like

```
val widget = WidgetBuilder().apply {
  width = 1  // instead I need .setWidth(1)
  height = 2
  weight = 3
  name = "my widget"
}.build()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Kotlin compiler only recognizes it as a property if there is a getter with equal or greater visibility as the setter. This is because there is no such thing in Kotlin as a property with no getter. ([See last sentence in this section.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters))

> Note that, if the Java class only has a setter, it isn't visible as a property in Kotlin because Kotlin doesn't support set-only properties.

You can manually write extension properties for this class that make the property access syntax available to you, although some would probably consider it an anti-pattern to have a non-functional getter for a property. But you can control the visibility of your extension properties, so it may be fine.

```
var WidgetBuilder.width: Int
    @Deprecated("Getter is unsupported.", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    get() = error("unsupported")
    set(value) { setWidth(value) }
```

And alternative for a builder would be to make a single extension function with all the parameters you might set on it, along with default values. Then you can use [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments) to get syntax somewhat similar to your example with `apply`.

FWIW, I just use the chained method calls as intended when working with Java builders.

Comment: Could you mark the getter as deprecated, to give a stronger warning not to use it?

Comment: @gidds Good idea, I added that. Then trying to use it will give a compiler warning.